# Is it possible to $\text{dist}(A,B)=0$ with $g(A)\subset (0,\epsilon)$ and $g(B)\subset (2\epsilon,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot \|)$ be a complete (infinite-dimensional) normed vector space and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function, $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and for some $\epsilon>0$ denote $A:=f^{-1}[c-2\epsilon,c+2\epsilon]$, $B:=f^{-1}[c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon]$. Then of course both  $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets and I want to prove that $\text{dist}(A^c,B)>0$, where $A^c$ is the complement set of $A$ and $\text{dist}(A^c,B):=\inf\left\{\|x-y\|;x\in A^c,y\in B\right\}$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose by contradiction that $\text{dist}(A^c,B)=0$, then by definition there exist two sequences $(x_n)\subset B$ and $(y_n)\subset A^c$ such that $\|x_n-y_n\|\to 0$, for example we can take such sequences in such a way that $\|x_n-y_n\|\leq 1/n$. We can assume that $y_n\in\partial A^c$. Since for $x\in A^c$ we have $g(x):=|f(x)-c|\geq 2\epsilon$ and for  $x\in B$ we have $g(x)=|f(x)-c|\leq\epsilon$, the existence of such sequence seems impossible. So I've take the set U of all elements $x\in X$ such that $|f(x)-c|\in(\epsilon,2\epsilon+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$, by continuity of $f$, $U$ is cleary open, so I've tried to show that there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in U$ (since $x_n$ is "converging" to $\partial A^c$, and $U$ is a neighborhood of $\partial A^c$), but I was not able to prove such assertion.

Is my attempt in the correct way? If not, what can I do to improve? I want some hints, thanks.

Comment: If $f$ is $C^1$ then it is almost linear in the neighborhood of $0$. In words $f(x_n -y_n)$ is almost $f(x_n) -f(y_n)$

Comment: @Salcio How can this be useful?

Comment: First off, this is a part of assumptions. You never used in your solution the fact that $X$ is linear space or that $f$ is smooth. Second, if $f(x_n  -y_n) = f(x_n) - f(y_n)$  and $f(0)=0$ then you are done. And if $f(0) $ is not zero then you can look at $f(x) -f(0)$.

Comment: @Salcio Can you elaborate in a better way? I did not get it.

Comment: If $f$ is smooth around zero and $f(0) =0$ it means that there is a linear map, say $F$ such that $f(x) = F(x) + o(|x|)$ for $x$ small enough.Then use your estimations.

Comment: @Salcio So $f(x_n-y_n)=F(x_n)-F(y_n) +o(|x_n-y_n|)$, since $f(0)=0$ we have $f(x_n-y_n)\to 0$ and therefore $F(x_n)-F(y_n)\to 0$. How this helps?

Comment: So $f(x_n) -f(y_n)$ tends to zero.

Comment: @Salcio I was not able to show that $f(x_n)-f(y_n)$ tends to zero. We have that $f(x_n)-f(y_n)=f^\prime(y_n)(x_n-y_n)+r_n(x_n-y_n)$. But how can we relate this to $f^\prime(0)=F?$. Or maybe $f(x_n)=F(x_n)+r(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)=F(y_n)+r(y_n)$, but again, I was not able to show that $r(x_n)-r(y_n)\to 0$. (by subtractin one equation from another).